# Plotting points from a function on a unit sphere using matplotlib

Tags: python, plot

I am trying to plot the following function on a unit sphere, the points should be on the sphere and fill up the whole sphere however some of the points are falling off. Any suggestions why? I believe it is because the sphere is not spanning 1,1,1 3D grid but I am not sure how to edit my code to fix this.

```
from itertools import product, combinations
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

def d(kx,ky):
    M = 1
    B = 1
    vf = 1
    kxx,kyy = np.meshgrid(kx,ky)

    x = (vf*kxx)/(np.sqrt(((((vf**2)*(kxx**2)))+((vf**2)*(kyy**2))+(M-B*(kxx**2+(kyy**2)))**2)))
    y = (vf*kxx)/(np.sqrt(((((vf**2)*(kxx**2)))+((vf**2)*(kyy**2))+(M-B*(kxx**2+(kyy**2)))**2))) 
    z = (M-B*(kxx**2+(kyy**2)))/(np.sqrt(((((vf**2)*(kxx**2)))+((vf**2)*(kyy**2))+(M-B*(kxx**2+(kyy**2)))**2)))
    return x,y,z




kx = np.linspace(-2, 2, 10)


ky = np.linspace(-2, 2, 10)

xi, yi, zi = d(kx,ky)




phi = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
phi, theta = np.meshgrid(phi, theta)

x = np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta)
y = np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
z = np.cos(phi)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1.))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, color="w", rstride=1, cstride=1)
ax.scatter(xi,yi,zi,color="k",s=20)

plt.show()
```

Thank you kindly,

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of `d(kx,ky)`?

Comment: It is a function that is being plotted on the sphere it produces the points to be plotted

Comment: I mean how did you come out with this equation? Is that a math formula or something?